# How to find maximal word ladder?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I would like to find the *word ladder* of maximal length for a given dictionary. A *word ladder* is a sequence of words such that each word differs from the previous word in only one position.

I am going to implement the following algorithm:

- read the words from the dictionary and group them by their length
- for each group create a `map`, which maps the each word to other words, which differ from it in only one position (this `map` is a graph implemented as adjacency lists)
- for each group find the shortest paths between *every pair* of "nodes" -- words in the `map` (using `bfs`)
- find the maximal shortest path.

I guess the algorithm works. Now I wonder if it is optimal from the performance point of view. How would you optimize it?

Comment: *sniff sniff* I detect a whiff of 'school' and a hint of 'homework' wafting around...

Comment: Maximal length and maximal shortest path are two very different things. What do you want?

Comment: If I'm getting it right, you are missing the importance of the order for the words in the ladder. [song - gong - gone] vs [gong - song]. The length will be higher or lower depending on the order of the words, not only the mapping from each word to the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to us question varies greatly depending on what you're asking for.

The algorithm you have posted here will give you the pair of words that have the longest shortest word ladder between them.  This is called the *diameter* of the word graph.  If you want to find this, the approach you have here should be fine.

If you want to actually find the longest word ladder in the dictionary (that is, you want to find the longest chain of words that differ only by one letter at a time), then if you exclude word ladders with cycles in them the problem is NP-hard (by a reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem), meaning that it is conjectured that there is no efficient algorithm for solving the problem.  You would probably have to brute-force search he word list by listing off all possible word ladders.  This, unfortunately, is completely infeasible in any reasonably-sized dictionary there would be a patently absurd number of ladders to try.

In short, if you are looking for the graph diameter, your solution is pretty good.  If you are looking to find the actual longest word ladder, then chances are that you will never be able to get the answer, since the search space is too huge and the problem is known to be theoretically difficult.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain a little bit how you reduce the longest word ladder to the Hamiltonian path?

Comment: @Michael Given an instance of longest word ladder, construct a graph with a vertex for each word and an edge between pairs of words that differ in only one position. In order to show that longest word ladder is hard, you need the other direction: a reduction from longest path to longest word ladder. One idea is, given a graph G = ({1,…,n}, E), to make words of length n. Each vertex i corresponds to a word a…aba…a with b at position i. Each edge (i, j) corresponds to a word a…aba…aba…a with b at positions i and j. We also need the all a's word and a long ladder to prevent starting at an edge.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is a way to compute the diameter of a graph that might be faster for sparse graphs where there are a few very long shortest paths.

1) Compute the minimum spanning tree for the graph.

2) The diameter of the minimum spanning tree can be found in two BFSs. Start the first from an arbitrary point on the tree. Start the second from a point which is a furthest point in the tree from the first point. This works because if you assign an arbitrary root to the tree, the diameter is the sum of two longest distances from the root, and your first BFS finds one of them.

3) Assign an fairly arbitrary root halfway along the diameter of the minimum spanning tree. An upper bound to a diameter starting from point X is the sum of the distance of X from that root and maximum distance of any node from that root. This is only an upper bound, because the shortest distance between two nodes does not necessarily follow the minimum spanning tree.

4) Do BFS searchs from nodes in non-increasing order of their distance from root in the minimum spanning tree. At the beginning of each search you have an upper bound from the tree of a graph diameter starting at that node. You can stop doing BFS searches when that upper bound is no greater than the largest diameter found so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is a full implementation of this task in Mathematica, with background information at

http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/11/the-longest-word-ladder-puzzle-ever/